# How to change page in libreoffice by terminal?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

To open a document in the terminal, simply carry out the following command in the terminal:

```
libreoffice -show filename.odp
```

In this example, in addition to opening the .odp file it will also open extended. But my doubt is, after the open file, which commands can I pass to the terminal to go to the next page or previous page.

I'm looking for something like:

```
libreoffice filename.odp nextpage

libreoffice filename.odp page=2

libreoffice filename.odp less

libreoffice -page-label=2 filename.odp
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: im afraid there is no way to do this from cli, you will have to edit the slideshow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xdotool` to the rescue.

Write a little script (install `xdotool` first if you haven't already):

```
#!/bin/bash
mywindow=$(xdotool search --class libreoffice)
xdotool windowactivate $mywindow && xdotool key --window $mywindow Next
```

This finds the handle of the Libreoffice window (make sure that you have only one open), activates it (i.e. brings it to the foreground) and sends the `Next` keystroke to it. `Next` is the official name for the keystroke event associated with the <kbd>PageDown</kbd> button (<kbd>PageUp</kbd> would be `Prior`, I had to look that up using the `xev` command).

Save the script, make it executable, and execute it.

For some reason though, it doesn't always work the first time. In LO Writer, for example, it would put the cursor at the bottom of the first page. Subsequent executions would actually page through the document. I haven't tried it with an Impress presentation though.

Comment: I will learn how to work with xdotool, since I have never used xdotool. thank you.

Comment: If you feel this answer adequately addresses your question, please tick the mark at the left of it.